# How to return multiple rows in one to many relationship

Tags: mysql, sql, join, foreign-keys, relationship

I have to tables in database with name customers and vehicles both are joined with one to many relationship.Customers have two record with customer_id=1 and 2 and vehicles have two records with customer_id=1 mapped with vehicle_id=1 and 2 and customer_id=2 mapped with vehicle_id=3
customers table

```
╦══════════════╦════════════════════╗
║ customer_id  ║       name         ║
╬══════════════╬════════════════════╣
║           1  ║      pranav        ║
║           2  ║      akshay        ║
╩══════════════╩════════════════════╝
```

vehicles table

```
╦══════════════╦════════════════════╗═════════════╗
║  vehicle_id  ║    vehicle_name    ║customer_id  ║      | 
╬══════════════╬════════════════════╣═════════════║      
║           1  ║      activa        ║    1        ║
║           2  ║      access        ║    1        ║
║           3  ║      bullet        ║    2        ║
╩══════════════╩════════════════════╝═════════════╝
```

i am getting this

```
╦══════════════╦════════════════════╗═════════════╗
║  vehicle_id  ║    vehicle_name    ║    name     ║
╬══════════════╬════════════════════╣═════════════║      
║           1  ║      activa        ║   pranav    ║
║           3  ║      bullet        ║   akshay    ║
╩══════════════╩════════════════════╝═════════════╝
```

expected output----

```
╦══════════════╦════════════════════╗═════════════╗
║  vehicle_id  ║    vehicle_name    ║    name     ║
╬══════════════╬════════════════════╣═════════════║      
║           1  ║      activa        ║   pranav    ║
║           2  ║      access        ║   pranav    ║
║           3  ║      bullet        ║   akshay    ║
╩══════════════╩════════════════════╝═════════════╝
```

I am using this query

```
SELECT vehicle_id,vehicle_name,customers.name 
FROM customers,vehicles 
WHERE customers.customer_id=vehicles.vehicle_id
```

Comment: What query are you using?  This looks like a simple `join`.

Comment: This is the query SELECT vehicle_id,vehicle_name,customers.name from customers,vehicles WHERE customers.customer_id=vehicles. vehicle_id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax.

Your problem is that you have the wrong `JOIN` condition.  You want:

```
select v.vehicle_id, v.vehicle_name, c.name
from customers c join 
     vehicles v
     on c.customer_id = v.customer_id;
```

Notes:

- Qualify *all* column names in your query when you have more than one table reference.
- Use table aliases so the query is easier to write and to read.